# Can't Call StartActivityForResult in Anko

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I'm pretty new to android, and I'm trying to learn it with kotlin.  In this code

```
mHelp.setOnClickListener {context.startActivity<HelpActivity>()}
mSettings.setOnClickListener {
    context.startActivityForResult<LocalSettingsActivity>(
          LOCAL_SETTINGS_REQUEST,
          "coords" to this.board.mCoords,
          "drag" to this.mWhiteStones[0].drag )
}
```

the call to `startActivity` works fine, but I get a syntax error on the call to `startActivityForResult`.  The error says that it's a receiver type mismatch, and that the receiver should be an `Activity` or a `Fragment`.  On the other hand, the receiver for `StartActivity` can be a `Fragment`, a `Context`, or an `AnkoContext<*>` (whatever that is).

Of course, I can make this work (I think) by building the `Intent` and not using `anko.StartActivityForResult`, but I'd to understand what's going on.

It has occurred to me that perhaps I've got my code organized all wrong.  The code above is in a custom `ViewGroup` that has the `ImageButtons` mHelp and mSettings as children, and `context` is the `Context` passed to the `ViewGroup`'s primary constructor.  Should I perhaps be setting the `onClickListeners` in the `Activity` that manages the custom `ViewGroup`?  If not, how would I call `StartActivityForResult`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`startActivityForResult` can only be called on an `Activity` because only an `Activity` can receive a result from another finishing `Activity`. There are a few solutions, probably the easiest would be to change your custom `ViewGroup` so that it accepts an `Activity` instead of just a `Context`, or, if you know you will only use that `ViewGroup` from an `Activity`, just cast the `Context` to an `Activity`.

You are right though when you say that your code could probably be organized better, to circumvent this problem altogether. Just following separation of concerns, your `ViewGroup` should not be responsible for navigation actions in your App. The `ViewGroup` could for example allow listeners to register for the event that right now triggers the navigation action. This way, the `Activity` can register for that event, do the navigation itself and handle the result outside of the `ViewGroup`.

Comment: Thank you for this enlightening answer.  I'm going to try the quick-and-dirty solution (casting to Activity) for now, because I need to get a working app to show people.  As soon as that's out the door, I'll try to refactor everything intelligently.