# Why can't I use startActivityForResult in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I hope to open a activity for result in Kotlin.

I have read the artical [Can't Call StartActivityForResult in Anko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45225642/cant-call-startactivityforresult-in-anko)

So I convert AppCompatActivity as  Activity

But the code  `(mContext as Activity).startActivityForResult<UIAddEditBackup>(requestCode = 1, "id" to 2L)`  doesn't run yet, why?

**My Code**

```
class UIMain : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mContext: Context

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main)
         mContext = this
         btnExit.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity<UIAddEditBackup>("id" to 2L)  //OK
            (mContext as Activity).startActivityForResult<UIAddEditBackup>(requestCode = 1, "id" to 2L) //Error          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are misunderstanding the link. It does say `startActivityForResult` cannot be called on Context, which includes not only Activities but also Services, ApplicationContexts, Applications, and so on. It does say `startActivityForResult` should be called on Activities. However, AppCompatActivity is also an Activity. The conversion is unnecessary, and using `mContext` is useless. Just remove `(mContext as Activity).` in front of the `startActivityForResult`.

Comment: But an error hint is displayed  -    None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
startActivityForResult(Intent!, Int) defined in ui.UIMain
startActivityForResult(Intent!, Int, Bundle?) defined in ui.UIMain when I use `startActivityForResult<UIAddEditBackup>(requestCode = 1, "id" to 2L)`

Comment: I have import org.jetbrains.anko.*

Comment: startActivity<UIAddEditBackup>("id" to 2L)  is OK

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html *When a function is called with both positional and named arguments, all the positional arguments should be placed before the first named one. For example, the call f(1, y = 2) is allowed, but f(x = 1, 2) is not.*

Comment: You should use `startActivityForResult<UIAddEditBackup>(1, "id" to 2L)` or `startActivityForResult<UIAddEditBackup>(requestCode = 1, params=*arrayOf("id" to 2L))` OK. I think this is the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Kotlin Offical Doc on named arguments](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#named-arguments),

> When a function is called with both positional and named arguments, all the positional arguments should be placed before the first named one. For example, the call `f(1, y = 2)` is allowed, but `f(x = 1, 2)` is not.

You are using `startActivityForResult<UIAddEditBackup>(requestCode = 1, "id" to 2L)`. This is the case.

So, fix like these:

```
startActivityForResult<UIAddEditBackup>(1, "id" to 2L)
```

or

```
startActivityForResult<UIAddEditBackup>(requestCode = 1, params = *arrayOf("id" to 2L))
```

(Prototype of Anko startActivityForResult is `inline fun <reified T: Activity> Activity.startActivityForResult(requestCode: Int, vararg params: Pair<String, Any?>)`).

Referring ([the same page above](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#named-arguments))

> Variable number of arguments (vararg) can be passed in the named form by using the spread operator:
>
> `fun foo(vararg strings: String) { /* ... */ }`
>
> `foo(strings = *arrayOf("a", "b", "c"))`

`(mContext as Activity).` is not necessary in this case.